How to make new pandas DataFrame with columns as old index_column pairs
I have two pandas DataFrames:
object_1df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['a', 1], ['b', 2]],
    columns=['letter', 'number'])
object_2df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['b', 3, 'cat'], ['c', 4, 'dog']],
    columns=['letter', 'number', 'animal'])

  letter  number
0      a       1
1      b       2

  letter  number animal
0      b       3    cat
1      c       4    dog

I need to make a catalog of one row for each DataFrame and columns equal to the number of elements. The final form should be one row for each df with the columns:
a_letter  a_number b_letter  b_number b_animal c_letter  c_number c_animal

I have attempted the very ugly:
objects = [object_1df, object_2df]

catalog = pd.DataFrame()
for objectdf in objects:
    object_row = pd.DataFrame()
    for letter in objectdf['letter']:
        for column in objectdf.columns:
            object_row[f'{letter}_{column}'] = objectdf[column].loc[
                objectdf['letter'] == letter]
    catalog = pd.concat([catalog, object_row], ignore_index=True)
display(catalog)

which outputs the undesired result:
  a_letter  a_number b_letter  b_number b_animal c_letter  c_number c_animal
0        a       1.0      NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN       NaN      NaN
1      NaN       NaN        b       3.0      cat      NaN       NaN      NaN

This result essentially only counts the first row from each df, and gives NaNs everywhere else. What would be a correct way of doing this?

Please don't post pictures of text. I fixed it for you. In the future, instead of images, copy the text itself and format it as code (for print(df)) or as tables (from print(df.to_markdown()).

Please include the desired output in the question.

Flattening the df like this gives the desired outcome:
objects = [object_1df, object_2df]

catalog = pd.DataFrame()
for df in objects:
    df.set_index('letter', inplace=True)
    flattened_data = {
        f'{index}_{col}': df.loc[index, col]
        for index in df.index
        for col in df.columns}
    flattened_df = pd.DataFrame([flattened_data])
    display(flattened_df)
    catalog = pd.concat([catalog, flattened_df], ignore_index=True)
display(catalog)

yields
   a_number  b_number b_animal  c_number c_animal
0       1.0         2      NaN       NaN      NaN
1       NaN         3      cat       4.0      dog


Oh, so you don't actually want a_letter, b_letter, c_letter. Please edit the question to clarify that.

Beside the point, but df.set_index('letter', inplace=True) modifies the original dfs, leading to errors if you try running the loop again. Instead I'd do df = df.set_index('letter').

You can melt each DataFrame, convert to Series after creating a new index, then concat:
dfs = [object_1df, object_2df]

out = (pd.concat((df.melt('letter')
                    .assign(index=lambda x: x['letter']+'_'+x['variable'])
                    .set_index('index')['value']
                  for df in dfs),
                 axis=1)
         .rename_axis(None)
         .T.reset_index(drop=True)
     )

Output:
  a_number b_number c_number b_animal c_animal
0      1.0      2.0      NaN      NaN      NaN
1      NaN        3        4      cat      dog

Alternative by first using concat, then reshaping:
dfs = [object_1df, object_2df]

out = (pd.concat(dict(enumerate(dfs)))
       .droplevel(-1).set_index('letter', append=True)
       .unstack().swaplevel(axis=1)
       )

out.columns = out.columns.map('_'.join)

Output:
   a_number  b_number  c_number a_animal b_animal c_animal
0       1.0       2.0       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
1       NaN       3.0       4.0      NaN      cat      dog

Note a different order of the columns.
